# Replacement for multitext

Tags: plugin, upgrade, ee2-upgrades, field-conversion

I am upgrading a 1.7 site that used Mark Huot's MultiText field extensively.  I'm trying to identify a similar solution for 2.6.1.  (The multitext fields were used to provide captions for images in the 1.7 version of the site.)

It appears that the Matrix plug in is the best option.  However, the data format of these two plugins is different.  I have a lot of data formatted as MultiText.  Is there any way to convert the data to Matrix data format?

Answer (score 1):

[Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) is perfect for your needs, and was available for EE1 too.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the internal representation is the same as multitext's?  One issue I ,ogjht face is migrating the data from the old to new format (should that be necessary).

Comment: Alas no they will be completely different and there will be no alternative in EE2 that will be saved in the same format unless the developer has chosen to write an EE2 version and written a conversion/update, but I know this add-on isn't available for EE2. You could export the data via SQL and import using a Data import add-on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last part?  "export the data via SQL and import using a Data import add-on. "  Which "data import add-on" would do this for me?  At this point I'm thinking I may have to 1)  Learn the internal formats of both multitext and matrix 2) Identify which fields contain the data 3) Write an app to convert between the two formats 4) Run it and change the type to matrix.  It would be nice if I didn't have to do all this work (even though I find that type of project fun.)

Comment: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/data-import can export from a database into EE and supports Matrix on import.

Comment: okay I will check it out.  I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep.  Thanks

Comment: You don't have to upvote it, just mark it as correct :)